# error LNK2019 when compiling

Tags: c++

I saw another post on here with a very similar problem to mine.  However, I could not get those suggestions to work.  I have installed NI488.2 Version 3.1.2.  I am using VC++ 10.0, but I have am using Visual Studio Command Prompt to run c code.

From the NI-VISA Manual, I have typed out the code below.  When I compile it, I get this error:  error LNK2019: unresolved external error symbol_viOpenDefaultRM@4 referenced in function_main.  I found the visa32.lib and moved in into the lib folder for Visual Studio.  It did not work unfortunately.  Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "visa.h"

#define MAX_CNT 200

int main(void)
{

    ViStatus status;
    ViSession defaultRM, instr;
    ViUInt32 retCount;
    ViChar buffer[MAX_CNT];

    status = viOpenDefaultRM(&defaultRM);
    if (status <VI_SUCCESS){
        return -1;
    }
```

}

Comment: You need to tell the linker to link `visa32.lib`. Just dropping it in a folder won't do anything.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  Do I link this in my .c file?  I am really not sure how to link a library.  I found this line online as an example but I am not sure what to do with it, $ gcc -o myprog myprog.c  -L/home/newhall/lib -lmine

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the linker to link `visa32.lib`. In Visual Studio, add it to the list at the following location:

> Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies

If you're compiling on the command line, add `/link visa32.lib` to your compile command, like so:

```
cl test.cpp /link visa32.lib
```

Comment: I typing my c code in Notepad and running it using Visual Studio Command Prompt.  Is it still possible to link it like that?